# How should I add links to other pages/posts from my post?

Tags: posts, permalinks, links

I'm wondering how should I link to other posts from one of my posts. Ideally I would use a function like get_permalink() but php is not available in post content, so how can I link to other pages ensuring the links won't break if I change the post/pages slugs?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. Both involve using the post ID because that doesn't change.

1. You could use the ugly URL in the form of `http://www.example.com/?p=23` where `?p=23` would be the ID of the post.
2. You can use a shortcode that accepts the post ID and outputs a link using `get_permalink()`.

The following shortcode would be used like this.

```
[postlink id=23]Some link text goes here[/postlink]
```

And here is the function.

```php
function postlink_id_to_slug( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => ''
), $atts ) );

if ( $id == '' || ! is_numeric( $id ) || $content == null) return false;

return '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'postlink', 'postlink_id_to_slug' );
```

I should mention that there are a number of ways to [find the ID of a post](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-find-post-category-tag-comments-or-user-id-in-wordpress/). One way is to open the post in the post editor and then find `post=xx` in the URL in your browser's address field where `xx` is the numerical ID.

---

Just to know: [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-link-shortcode/) plugin does same thing in a more flexible manner.

Comment: @G.M. You should offer that up as an answer so people will see it.

Comment: Just edited your answer. All the honors to you ;)